# List all nodequeues a node belongs to

Tags: 6, nodes

Given I have a node, how to programmatically find out all the nodequeues it belongs to? Is there any ready functionality in Drupal 6 or do I just have query this from the DB myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using:

```
$queues = nodequeue_load_queues(array_keys(nodequeue_get_all_qids())); // Cached by default
$subqueues = nodequeue_get_subqueues_by_node($queues, $node);
nodequeue_set_subqueue_positions($subqueues, $node->nid);
$nodequeues = array();

if (is_array($subqueues)) {
  foreach ($subqueues as $sqid => $subqueue) {
    if (!empty($subqueue->position)) {
      $nodequeues[] = $sqid;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have loaded the node in `$node` you can do:

```
$queues = nodequeue_load_queues_by_type($node->type, 'links');
$subqueues = nodequeue_get_subqueues_by_node($queues, $node);
```